# Await a stable state in HTML5 specs

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In the HTML5 specs there is a notion of await a stable state (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#await-a-stable-state) Can someone explain it with an example what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

An example of this is an asynchronous [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). You can make a request like this:

```
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
...
```

During the request, you can look at the state of `myRequest` -- specifically, `myRequest.readyState`. Until the request finishes, the request is not in a stable state.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's an internal thing to explain how some algorithms work. Some parts of those algorithms runs synchronously, and the other ones wait a stable state before running.

> When the user agent is to [**provide a stable state**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#provide-a-stable-state), if any
>   asynchronously-running algorithms are [**awaiting a stable state**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#await-a-stable-state),
>   then the user agent must run their [**synchronous section**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#synchronous-section) and then
>   resume running their asynchronous algorithm (if appropriate).

For example, images await a stable state:

> When the user agent is to [**update the image data**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#update-the-image-data) of an [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element) element, it
>   must run the following steps:
>
> - Return the [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element) element to the [unavailable](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#img-none) state.
> - [...]
> - Asynchronously [await a stable state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#await-a-stable-state), allowing the [task](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#concept-task) that invoked this algorithm to continue. The [synchronous section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#synchronous-section)
>     consists of all the remaining steps of this algorithm until the
>     algorithm says the [synchronous section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#synchronous-section) has ended. (Steps in
>     [synchronous sections](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#synchronous-section) are marked with `⌛`.)
> - `⌛` If another instance of this algorithm for this [`img`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element) element was started after this instance (even if it aborted and is no
>     longer running), then abort these steps.
> - `⌛` [...]
> - End the [synchronous section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#synchronous-section), continuing the remaining steps asynchronously, but without missing any data from the [fetch](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#fetch)
>     algorithm.
> - As soon as possible, jump to the first applicable entry from the following list: [...]